# Docker image > google/cadvisor:latest

Tags: docker, cadvisor

I don't recall starting this container:

```
IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS         
google/cadvisor:latest                   "/usr/bin/cadvisor -l"   2 days ago          Exited (0) 2 days ago
```

which has now exited. Any idea whether it's a good idea to do a `docker rm` on it?

E.g. is it being used by Docker or Google somewhere for monitoring?

Comment: Made by google and used for monitoring container resource usage, safe to remove, if you don't need it. https://github.com/google/cadvisor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) (short for "container advisor") is a project by Google that collects monitoring data from your Docker Engine, e.g. number of running containers, ressource usage per container and so on.

If you do not recall starting this container yourself, it is possible that some other application has started it. While I am not aware of any application that does this without asking, I could very well imagine that you are running a management application that uses cAdvisor for monitoring other containers on the host.

It is certainly not part of Docker itself, but as it is stopped there should be no harm in removing it.

Answer (score 0):

cAdvsior is the container's metric collection docker container, normally it can be merged with node-exporter + grafana + prometheus + alertmanager for full fledge monitoring system for your containerized infrastructure.